# Java Threaded Server Client Messaging Application

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to make a threaded server client messaging application in java. I'm having trouble sending a message that a client sent to every other client connected to the server. I added all connected threads to an array list so when a message is sent I can iterate over the list and send it to all the clients but this doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong here?

When one client is connected it works perfectly the server echos everything the client says. When two clients are connected only the client that sent the message gets the message. If that same client though send another message the server seems to get hung up and no messages get echoed.

**Threaded Server Code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ThreadedSever
{
  private static final int port=5000;
  ArrayList<ServerThread> clientList = new ArrayList<ServerThread>();

  //Threaded Server
  public ThreadedSever(){
     System.out.println("A multi-threaded server has started...");
     ServerSocket serverSocket = null; 
     try {
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Could not create a server socket: " + e);
     }
     //Chat with the client until breaks connection or says bye
     try{
         while(true){
             System.out.println("Waiting for client communication");
             Socket currentSocket = serverSocket.accept();
             //Create a new thread to deal with this connection
             clientList.add(new ServerThread(currentSocket));
             System.out.println(clientList);
         }

     }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Fatal Server Error!");
     }
  }
   //Inner class to handle individual commincation
   private class ServerThread extends Thread{
   //Possible add name to then get private messages
   private Socket sock;
   private DataInputStream in = null;
   private DataOutputStream out = null;

   public ServerThread(Socket sock){
       try{
           this.sock = sock;
           in = new DataInputStream(this.sock.getInputStream());
           out = new DataOutputStream(this.sock.getOutputStream());
           System.out.print("New client connection established");
           out.writeUTF("Type bye to exit, otherwise, prepare to be echoed");
           start();
       }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("Oops");
       }
   }
   public void run(){
     try{
        String what = new String("");
        while(!what.toLowerCase().equals("bye")){
            what = in.readUTF();
            echoMessage(what);

        }
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Connection to current client has been broken");
     }
     finally{
       try{
           sock.close();
       }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("Error socket could not be closed");
       }
     }
   }
   public void echoMessage(String what){
     try{
      for (ServerThread Thread: clientList) {
            in = Thread.in;
            out = Thread.out;

            System.out.println("Client told me: " + what);
            out.writeUTF(what);
      }
     }catch(Exception e){

     }
   }
  }
  public static void main(){
    new ThreadedSever();
  }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class simpleClient
{
    private static final int port= 5000;
    private static String server = "localhost";
    private static Socket socket = null;
    private static DataInputStream input = null;
    private static DataOutputStream output = null;
    private static InputStreamReader inReader = null;
    private static BufferedReader stdin = null;

    public static void main(){
        try{
            socket = new Socket(server, port);
        }catch(UnknownHostException e){
            System.err.println("Unknow IP address for server");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("No server found at specified port");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Something happened!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        try{
            input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            inReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            stdin = new BufferedReader(inReader);
            String what = new String("");
            String response;
            while(!what.toLowerCase().equals("bye")){
                // Expect something from the server and output it when it arrives
                response = input.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Server said  \"" + response + "\"");
                //Read a line from the user and send it to the server
                what = stdin.readLine();
                output.writeUTF(what);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("Broken connection with server");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean, 'doesn't seem to be working'?  What specifically problem is happening?  Is it throwing an Exception?  Is it exiting without doing anything?  What specific output do you expect and what are you actually seeing?

Comment: @astidham203 edited the question to explain more.